# How do I run a single unit test method in xcode without rebuilding?

Tags: ios, xcode

How do I run a single unit test method in xcode without rebuilding?  Every time I press the diamond xcode rebuilds. How can I fix this so that I can simply re-run the test without rebuilding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if previous versions had this option, but Xcode 13 allows running a single test without rebuilding by accessing the context menu for that particular test.

You can access the context menu via right click, or cmd+click on the diamond corresponding to the test:

[image]

---

If your last test action was to run the test you're interested into, you can also re-launch the test via the Product->Perform Action menu:

[image]

Too bad the menu doesn't come with a default key binding, however one is not hard to set, just go to Preferences->Key Bindings:

[image]

This way, you can keep editing the production code, and use the keyboard to keep relaunching the same test as long as needed.